# Can't get file path by uri?

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider

My app is A, a player app, now i want to get a video path by uri which is provided by another app B,below is the provider of app B:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="com.xxx.xxx.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@ref/0x7f100000" />
</provider>
```

My app A can get the uri provided by app B, but i can't get the real path from the uri using code below:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);
        if (null != cursor) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                String[] names = cursor.getColumnNames();
                if (index > -1) {
                    data = cursor.getString(index);
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
```

is it because of the provided declared as exported = false? but also it declared grantUriPermissions = true. help me, thans!

Comment: why don't you try getAbslutePath method over uri to get actual path?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed thanks, using input stream means to make a copy of the original file, but i don't want to create another new file. isn't any way else?